# These jQuery custom check boxes aren't working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am trying to use these custom MacOSX-style check boxes on my site (it's a jQuery plugin), but when I check one, it doesn't actually trigger the `$('#input').is(':checked');` until you uncheck and then it gets messed up.

Whenever you check a box, I add some CSS to the line that is checked to add a yellow background to it. But, I'm having trouble with them. This image explains it below:

[image]

I don't understand why it does this. This is my `checkIt()` function that adds the yellow background when you check a line:

```
function checkIt(id) {
    if ($('#checkbox_' + id).is(':checked')) {
        $('#' + id).addClass("selected");
    }
    else {
        $('#' + id).removeClass("selected");
    }
}
```

And I call this onclick when the checkbox is clicked. Here is some example markup that is generated by the PHP:

```
<span class="inbox_check_holder">
<input type="checkbox" value="96874" onclick="checkIt(96874)" id="checkbox_96874" class="inbox_check" />
<div class="star_clicker" id="star_96874" onclick="addStar(96874)" title="Not starred"><span id="starimg_96874" class="not_starred"></span></div>
</span>
```

I'm thinking it is something to do with this custom checkbox jQuery plugin adding in extra elements over the `<input />`.

Here's the [jQuery checkbox plugin page](http://widowmaker.kiev.ua/checkbox/#form1) if you need to see it, they have tons of examples on it. (Obviously) I am using the "Safari" skin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$(".inbox_check").live("change",function(e){
e.stopPropagation();
if($(this).is(":checked"))
 $('#' + id).addClass("selected");
else
 $('#' + id).removeClass("selected");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BXjg7/3/

with jquery 1.7 you can use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$("body").on("change", ".inbox_check", function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    if($(this).is(":checked"))
     $('#' + id).addClass("selected");
    else
     $('#' + id).removeClass("selected");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BXjg7/10/

`delegate` example

```
$("body").delegate(".inbox_check","change", function(e){
e.stopPropagation();  
    if($(this).is(":checked"))
     $('#' + id).addClass("selected");
    else
     $('#' + id).removeClass("selected");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BXjg7/15/

Comment: Would I put that in my `checkIt()` function?

Comment: sorry i didnt mentioned it in the answer, you dont need the `onClick` event of the checkbox when using the above code

Comment: My PHP dynamically creates the HTML, and I have to pass the ID in the function which is why I'm using `onclick`. I don't like using `onclick` that much, but for this I have to because of the IDs that need to be passed.

Comment: if you are dynamically generating the html use `live`, or `delegate,` or `on` (jquery 1.7), updated the answer, also you have the class name you dont need the ids...

Comment: But then how do I highlight the background of the selected line? When you click a checkbox, it is supposed to change the background of the message line. (you can see in my screenshot above) And, `id` is no longer defined. I do understand that I can use `.inbox_check` for the `onchange`, but the ID of the line to change the background of the selected message is why i need to pass the ID.

Comment: I just solved that problem with your code :) Instead of `$('#' + id).addClass("selected");` I am now using .parent().parent() to add/remove the class from the parent of the parent container of the checkbox: `$(this).parent().parent().addClass("selected");`. And it works. Thanks for your help!! And I don't have to use onclick anymore. :) Also, when I said _dynamically_, I meant PHP. The markup is created by the PHP and the information is filled in from the MySQL database.

Comment: glad that helped, also insteas of `parent().parent()` you can use `.parents("selector")`...

Comment: Oh I can? Thanks! Since the line container that holds the whole line is a div, I can do `.parents("div")`? The checkbox holder is a span which is why I was originally using `.parent().parent()`.

Comment: yes you can or you can use the `closest` http://api.jquery.com/closest/ if there is no other div in between the span and the line container `div`